# Several questions about Local notification

Tags: android, codenameone, localnotification

I'am not a new Codename One user but this is my first time to use Local notification with this framework. In my app, i have a picker to allow the user to choose a time (hour and minutes). i recevied the time which is chosen with getTime() method. Now i want my local notification to trigger at that time. What is the correct value that i need to give at the second parameter of the `Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification()` function?

So far what I have is this sample but I don't understand how to apply it to my needs:

```
Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(notification, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
```

Comment: welcome to SO!  since you are asking about parameter values, can you give us a code snippet to give a clearer context?

Comment: Ok Thanks! Here is the prototype of the scheduleLocalNotification() function :Display.scheduleLocalNotification(LocalNotification n, long firstTime, int repeat). The second parameter of this function is the time to trigger the notification. Here is a sample: Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
        notification,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000,
        LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java doc of that method

> @param firstTime time in milliseconds when to schedule the
>   notification @param repeat repeat one of the following: REPEAT_NONE,
>   REPEAT_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, REPEAT_HALF_HOUR, REPEAT_HOUR, REPEAT_DAY,
>   REPEAT_WEEK

So you can use your Date object method `getTime()` to return the time in millis for that date object.

EDIT

Let's assume this is the callback for your time picker

```
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(); // This is the time now, so the day is set to today
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Display.scheduleLocalNotification(LocalNotification, date.getTime().getTime(), repeat);
}
```

Setting the second and millisecond is just to ensure the alarm goes off at the exact minute the user picked.

You can also change the day, month and year same as we changed the hour and minute.

Comment: Hello,I don't have Date object. I use the Time Picker only (and not Date/Time Picker) and the getTime() method of Picker class return in minutes the hour and the minutes choosen by the user. When i convert this value in millisecons and put it at the value of the firstTime parameter, i don't have the result that i want. For instance, if the user choose 7:05 as hour and minutes, the local notification must trigger at that time? This is my real question.

Comment: You need to set the values of the day/month/year correctly then you can use Calendar class and use the set(int, int) method to set the values for all units correctly, then use calender.getTime().getTime()

Comment: So what about the time value that i get from the Picker class? The one which is choosen by the user? Can you give me a code sample of what you say please?

Comment: Ok! i will make a try and i will come back to you. Thanks

Comment: FYI the answer seems correct so you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox next to it. This will give both you and @elmorabea points which are useful for various tasks within the site. Upvoting the answer (with the up arrow) also helps...